# imageslider working in chrome but in mozilla works only after printing some alert message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have image slider code it is working fine chrome and other browser but it is not working on mozilla .on page load if i print alert() then only it works in mozilla . i am reading image details from xml file. may be with alert at the back it gets time to load all image details.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getData();
    alert('START');
});
```

**GetData function :::**

```
function getData(){ 
    $.get('photos.xml', function(xml) {
        $('item', xml).each(function (k) {
            frontimg.push($(this).find('frontImg').text()); 
            stripimg.push($(this).find('stripImg').text());
            frontText.push($(this).find('frontTxt').text());
            fTitle.push($(this).find('title').text());
            fCity.push($(this).find('city').text());
            fYear.push($(this).find('compYear').text());
            fLoc.push($(this).find('loc').text());
            fType.push($(this).find('type').text());
            fRole.push($(this).find('role').text());
            arrBackImg.push($(this).find('backImg').text());    
            backText.push($(this).find('backTxt').text());
            frontDiv.push("<h2>"+fTitle[k]+"</h2>"+ "<h3>"+fCity[k]+"</h3><hr><h4>YEAR OF COMPLETION</h4>"+fYear[k]+"<hr><h4>LOCATION</h4>"+fLoc[k]+"<hr><h4>PROPERTY TYPE</h4>"+fType[k]+"<hr><h4>MAPLETREE'S TYPE</h4>"+fRole[k]);
            $('#myImageFlow').append('<div id="id'+k+'" alt="div'+k+'" class="sliderImage" width="280" height="425" style="visibility:hidden"> <div class="frontText" id="f'+k+'">'+frontDiv[k]+'</div><div class="borderdiv" id="b'+k+'"></div><div class="borderdiv1" id="b'+k+'"></div><div class="reflection" id="ref'+k+'"></div>  </div>');
        });

        $('font', xml).each(function (k) {
            var fontSize = $(this).find('size').text();
            var fontFamily = $(this).find('family').text();
            var fontColor = $(this).find('color').text();
            $(".frontText").css("font-family",fontFamily);  
            $(".frontText").css("font-size",fontSize);  
            $(".frontText").css("color",fontColor); 
        });

        $('label', xml).each(function (k) {
            fSize = $(this).find('fsize').text();
            fFamily = $(this).find('ffamily').text();
            fColor = $(this).find('fcolor').text();

            fpos=$(this).find('fpos').text();
            ftext=$(this).find('ftext').text();

            spos=$(this).find('spos').text();
            stext=$(this).find('stext').text();

            tpos=$(this).find('tpos').text();
            ttext=$(this).find('ttext').text();

            totalimages=$(this).find('totalimages').text();
            //alert("label pos is ="+tpos);
        });
    });
}
```

any suggestion if i can stylise alert box aur print some welcome in div so that it will work in mozilla.

Comment: could you also add the getData() function?

Comment: Agreed, Would be useful to see the getData function.

Comment: If your images are `img` elements, are the `width` and `height` attributes set?

Comment: @huddds  getData function added ...plz check

Comment: @Daryl  getData function added ...plz check

Comment: @thirtydot i am using div tag , by setting div backgroun-images

Comment: You can improve your chances of getting an answer if you include an example link showing the problem. Or, create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/ / http://jsbin.com/.

Comment: If you take the alert out and leave it a second or 2 does it then work?

Comment: @huddds no ... it dosen't, in html i am first reading from XML and then calling js file...so may b xml is not reading completely and JS is called which don;t get the details

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem could be without seeing the whole code, a jsfiddle would probably get a decent answer as recommended by @thirtydot